# Valgrind error: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) on a char array, even though the array is initialized

Tags: conditional-statements, valgrind, cs50

When I run this code I get the errors: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s) and Use of uninitialized value of size 8, both on line 50. I understand that I haven't put any characters/values into "lcword", but this shouldn't be a problem because I am not assigning the uninitialized values to anything, I'm putting some characters into the array to replace these unitialized values. I don't see any uninitialized values in the condition either - there is only j which is initialized. How should I resolve this problem?

```
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    char* lcword = malloc(46 * sizeof(char));
    for (int j = 0; j < 46; j++)
    {
        lcword[j] = tolower(word[j]); //This is line 50
    }

    unsigned int hash = 0;
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(lcword); i<n; i++)
    {
        hash = (hash << 2) ^ lcword[i];
    }
    free(lcword);
    return hash % N;
}
//Source of hash function: https://github.com/andycloke/Harvard-CS50-Solutions/blob/master/pset5/speller/dictionary.c
```

Here is the whole file (the hash function is being called in the check and the load functions):

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 65536;

// Hash table
node *table[N];
unsigned int sizeofdic = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    int i = hash(word);
    node *cursor = table[i];
    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if (strcasecmp(cursor->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cursor = cursor->next;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    char* lcword = malloc(46 * sizeof(char));
    for (int j = 0; j < 46; j++)
    {
        lcword[j] = tolower(word[j]);
    }

    unsigned int hash = 0;
    for (int i=0, n=strlen(lcword); i<n; i++)
    {
        hash = (hash << 2) ^ lcword[i];
    }
        free(lcword);
        return hash % N;
}


// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else     false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    node *newnode;
    int index;
    char *newword = malloc(46*sizeof(char));

    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", newword) != EOF)
    {
        sizeofdic++;
        newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
        strcpy(newnode->word, newword);
        index = hash(newnode->word);
        newnode->next = table[index];
        table[index] = newnode;
    }
    fclose(dict);
    free(newword);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet     loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
return sizeofdic;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else     false
bool unload(void)
{
    node *cursor;
    node *tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cursor = table[i];
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    free(cursor);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: it means `word` is not fully initialized, can you post your `dictionary.c` file?

Comment: Yeah sure, it's there.

Comment: Two ways to fix it:   change `j< 46` to `j < 46 && word[j] != '\0'`, or change `newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));` to  `newnode = calloc(1, sizeof(node));`.

Comment: Using calloc instead of malloc helped, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem is this: `j < 46`. It is, in many (most?) cases,reading past the end of "word".

Comment: Yes, he needs to check `word[j] != '\0'` too.